# Logic error resulting in inability to print given output

Tags: java, object, input, logic, java.util.scanner

When running this program, it does not print the encryption or decryption outputs, and prints the user prompt to enter a message, but does not actually allow for input.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CaesarShiftTester
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String alphabet[] = {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z"};

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you wish to:\n[1]Encrypt\n[2]Decrypt\n\n");
        while (!in.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter an integer value: ");
            in.nextLine();
        }
        int decision = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if(decision == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer value between 1-25 by which you desire to shift your message: ");
            while (!in.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter an integer value");
                in.nextLine();
            }
            int shift = in.nextInt();
            if(shift > 25 || shift < 1)
            {
                shift = 0;
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a phrase you wish to encrypt: ");
            while (!in.hasNextLine())
            {
                in.nextLine();
            }
            String entry= in.nextLine();
            entry = entry.toLowerCase();

            System.out.println(CaesarShiftEncryption.encrypt(alphabet, entry, shift));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer value between 1-25 by which you desire to shift your message: ");
            while (!in.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter an integer value: ");
                in.nextLine();
            }
            int shift = in.nextInt();
            if(shift > 25 || shift < 1)
            {
                shift = 0;
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a phrase you wish to decrypt: ");
            while (!in.hasNextLine())
            {
                in.nextLine();
            }
            String entry= in.nextLine();
            entry = entry.toLowerCase();

            System.out.println(CaesarShiftDecryption.decrypt(alphabet, entry, shift));
        }
    }
}
```

This class calls to these two classes:

```
public class CaesarShiftDecryption
{
    public static String decrypt(String str[], String in, int shift)
    {
        String decryption = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
        {
            int charval = in.charAt(i);
            if(charval-shift < 97 && charval < 123)
            {
                charval += 26;
            }
            if(charval > 96)
            {
                charval -= shift;
                String token = str[charval-97];
                decryption += token;
            }
            else
            {
                decryption += in.charAt(i);
            }
            charval = 0;
        }
        return decryption;
    }
}

public class CaesarShiftEncryption
{
    public static String encrypt(String str[], String in, int shift)
    {
        String encryption = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
        {
            int charval = in.charAt(i);
            if(charval+shift > 122 && charval < 123)
            {
                charval -= 26;
            }
            if(charval > 96)
            {
                charval += shift;
                String token = str[charval-97];
                encryption += token;
            }
            else
            {
                encryption += in.charAt(i);
            }
            charval = 0;
        }
        return encryption;
    }
}
```

However, I construct an additional scanner object, and my code for my tester appears as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CaesarShiftTester
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String alphabet[] = {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z"};

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you wish to:\n[1]Encrypt\n[2]Decrypt\n\n");
        while (!in.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter an integer value: ");
            in.nextLine();
        }
        int decision = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if(decision == 1)
        {
            Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter an integer value between 1-25 by which you desire to shift your message: ");
            while (!in.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter an integer value");
                in.nextLine();
            }
            int shift = in.nextInt();
            if(shift > 25 || shift < 1)
            {
                shift = 0;
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a phrase you wish to encrypt: ");
            while (!in1.hasNextLine())
            {
                in1.nextLine();
            }
            String entry= in1.nextLine();
            entry = entry.toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("\nThis is your encrypted message:\n" + CaesarShiftEncryption.encrypt(alphabet, entry, shift));
        }
        else
        {
            Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter an integer value between 1-25 by which you desire to shift your message: ");
            while (!in.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter an integer value: ");
                in.nextLine();
            }
            int shift = in.nextInt();
            if(shift > 25 || shift < 1)
            {
                shift = 0;
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a phrase you wish to decrypt: ");
            while (!in1.hasNextLine())
            {
                in.nextLine();
            }
            String entry= in1.nextLine();
            entry = entry.toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("\nThis is your decrypted message:\n" + CaesarShiftDecryption.decrypt(alphabet, entry, shift));
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this fixes this issue which occurs with the first version of this program? (I have experienced this before, but never known why--though I've fixed it this way [adding an additional scanner object to the input]).

Answer (score 0):

Changing to this should solve the problem

```
Old - String entry= in.nextLine();

New - String entry= in.next();
```

Comment: No it wouldn't, and the next method serves a completely different function.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there your problem is that your while is not well done
change this :

```
       while (!in.hasNextLine())
        {
            in.nextLine();
        }
        String entry= in.nextLine();
```

to :

```
        String entry = "";
        while(entry.equals(""))
        {
            entry = in.nextLine();
        }
```

Don't forget to change it in both of your function ;)

I just tried it and it's working for me ;)

UPDATE ***

You can see your problem by adding :

```
        String entry= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("entry//" + entry+"//");
```

output =

`Enter a phrase you wish to encrypt: 
entry////`

Comment: While this may be a fix, it doesn't address my question.

Comment: what was your question ? why does it break ?

Comment: Apparently my question wasn't as specified as I had thought it had been, I believe I drafted it in a txt file but hadn't posted my edited version. Re-read the last bit of my post. Again, sorry.

Comment: After some test it's just simple it never pass by the `while (!in.hasNextLine())` so it directly goes to which is consider as "" or null and all of this goes in the tolowerCase and to your function and crash :)